# ComboBox and ChoiceBox don`t show content

Tags: javafx

`ComboBox` and `CheckBox` set element's inside it https://ibb.co/7YWQfLh, but don't display this element's https://ibb.co/Mfy2mZb

I create boxes in different panes (`HBox`, `VBox`, `AnchorPane`, `GridPane`), result the same.
I used Enum and usual String and result the same.

```
public class TestFXController {

    @FXML
    private ComboBox<String> asd;

    @FXML
    private ChoiceBox<String> fgh;

    @FXML
    void initialize() {
        ObservableList<String> langs = 
            FXCollections.observableArrayList("Java", "JavaScript", "C#", "Python");
        asd = new ComboBox<>(langs);
        fgh = new ChoiceBox<>(langs);

    }
}
```

```xml
<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-    Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0"     xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="TestFXController">
   <children>
      <ComboBox fx:id="asd" prefWidth="150.0" />
      <ChoiceBox fx:id="fgh" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="70.0" prefWidth="150.0" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

What's wrong. I want this result.

https://metanit.com/java/javafx/pics/4.16.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Combo box and Choice box already exists as long as they have to correct fx:ids set in your FXML (asd, and fgh), so you don't need the following:

```
asd = new ComboBox<>(langs);
fgh = new ChoiceBox<>(langs);
```

From your initialize method you can for example set your items in the combo box like this:

```
ObservableList<String> langs = FXCollections.observableArrayList("Java", "JavaScript", "C#", "Python");
asd.setItems(langs);
```

That should work fine, it does for me as you can see in the image below, as long as you've got the correct fx:id set (which you look to have).

[image]

Hope it helps :)

Comment: I'm not sure why I didn't write .setItems instead, thank you fabian I updated my answer. As for ObservableList, I more or less just went with what he had. I might have answered a little too quickly, but I'll let him decide if he wants the Observable list or not for whatever reason.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to what Robert said if you want less code in your project you can add the items into the fxml like so

```
<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="TestFXController">
    <children>
        <ComboBox fx:id="asd" prefWidth="150.0">
            <items>
                <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
                    <String fx:value="Java" />
                    <String fx:value="JavaScript" />
                    <String fx:value="C#" />
                    <String fx:value="Python" />
                </FXCollections>
            </items>
        </ComboBox>
        <ChoiceBox fx:id="fgh" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="70.0" prefWidth="150.0">
            <items>
                <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
                    <String fx:value="Java" />
                    <String fx:value="JavaScript" />
                    <String fx:value="C#" />
                    <String fx:value="Python" />
                </FXCollections>
            </items>
        </ChoiceBox>
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: Thats interesting, I haven't seen that before! I am still somewhat new to JavaFX and am just trying to answer some small questions here and there which I think I can answer. This time I learned something as well.